# Webkitdirectory look only in top folder

Tags: html

I'm using webkitdirectory to get the video files from a selected folder:

```
<input class="btn btn-info" id="video" type="file" required webkitdirectory directory />
```

The issue I'm running into is the selected folder will have a subfolder with lots of video files that I don't want selected.

Is there a way to have webkitdirectory only look at the top folder chosen, and not add the files from the subfolder(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter filelist after selected folder.

Here is a solution. Hope to help, my friend :))

http://jsfiddle.net/pcrnhd8g/

```
<input type="file" id="picker" name="picker" webkitdirectory multiple  />

<div id="list">
  Pick a directory.
</div>  


<script>


let picker = document.getElementById('picker');

picker.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let files = event.target.files;
  let list = document.getElementById('list');
  list.innerHTML = 'You selected these files:';

  // get the files that not inlcude at subfolder
    files = Array.from(files).filter( function(s){     
    return !s.webkitRelativePath.includes('SubFolder'); 
});


  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i];
    list.innerHTML += '<br>' + file.webkitRelativePath;
  }
});

</script>
```